# htaccess 301 redirection for good seo and dynamic urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

i am planning to change my site urls and i dont want my old links which they allready indexed in google to be gone so i want to use this way to do and i am not sure about it.

i want to to redirect those links

```
http://domain.com/usa/mobiles-phones-pdas/ad/162/mobile-for-sale
http://domain.com/usa/mobiles-phones-pdas/mobile-phones/ad/162/mobile-for-sale
http://domain.com/usa/mobiles-phones-pdas/mobile-phones/blackberry/ad/162/mobile-for-sale
```

to be redirected to this url

```
http://domain.com/usa/ads-162.html
```

also the country ( usa ) it is not stick so it could be another country but the links are the same.

so which is the best SEO redirection method to keep my old links in google indexed.

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/.+?/ad/([0-9]+).+$ /$1/ads-$2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it redirect but the url in the page is still the old url dear